# how to insert multiple rows in excel between data

Tags: excel

I would like to add multiple rows between existing data.

I tired below macro code, but when I add 10 rows, it adding 10 rows after each existing data.

please help me

```
Sub test()
Dim j As Long, r As Range
j = InputBox("type the number of rows to be insered")

Set r = Range("A2")
Do
Range(r.Offset(1, 0), r.Offset(j, 0)).EntireRow.Insert
Set r = Cells(r.Row + j + 1, 1)
If r.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then Exit Do
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple code,

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
j = InputBox("type the number of rows to be insered")
For i = 1 To j
    Range("A2").EntireRow.Insert
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: could you please tell me what was the error in my code ?

Comment: @Aneesh an not entirely sure, but  i guess the problem is here `Cells(r.Row + j + 1, 1)`. Thats why rows are inserted multiple times